# MATLAB - Make an array of quaternions data

Tags: arrays, matlab, quaternions

I want to make an array with a set of quaternions data and i want to populate the array inside a loop. The problem is i can't put the quaternions data using a regular way to populate the array.
How do i can make it right?

this is what i've tried

```
for ii=1:size(acc,1)
    %  quaternion data
    qahrs = ifilt(acc(ii,:), gyro(ii,:), mag(ii,:));
    %     supposed to be an array of quaternions
    orientation(ii) = qahrs;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it guys!
Here's the solution

```
orientation = zeros('quaternion');
for ii=1:size(accCopy,1)
    qahrs = ifilt(accCopy(ii,:), gyro(ii,:), mag(ii,:));
    orientation(ii,1) = qahrs;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on dimensions of your quaternion data. If a single quaternion is (4x1) then:

```
orientation = zeros(4,n)
for ii=1:size(acc,1)
    %  quaternion data
    qahrs = ifilt(acc(ii,:), gyro(ii,:), mag(ii,:));
    %     supposed to be an array of quaternions
    orientation(:,ii) = qahrs;
end
```

and if it is (1x4)

```
orientation = zeros(n,4)
for ii=1:size(acc,1)
    %  quaternion data
    qahrs = ifilt(acc(ii,:), gyro(ii,:), mag(ii,:));
    %     supposed to be an array of quaternions
    orientation(ii,:) = qahrs;
end
```

I assumed that *n* is the number of quaternions.

Comment: i've tried this way but it's not working.
here's the output
--
The following error occurred converting from quaternion to double:
Conversion to double from quaternion is not possible.

Comment: It seems you use some dedicated quaternion class to store quaternions. In this case what you've tried should work. What is the error message when you try to execute your proposed solution?

Comment: well i did it. i initialized the orientation's variable with 'orientation = zeros('quaternion');' and populate it the same way with your suggestion. Thank you for your help btw